# What does this wordpress .htaccess rule do?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress, apache2

In the default .htaccess rules for a WordPress 4.7 multisite **subdomain** installation, I'm trying to understand the purpose for one particular rule.

First I'll present the rule on its own

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
```

In isolation, to me, it would appear that the rule would simply rewrite any url in wp-content or wp-admin or wp-includes to itself. Since it comes after the file system checks, we know it doesn't exist on the file system, so I'm at a loss for what it's trying to do.

Now here's the entirety of the suggested .htaccess file.  The rule is third from the end.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Any insight that anyone can shed would be fantastic. I'm getting an error - "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error." - whenever anyone tries to access any directory beyond wp-content/ that doesn't exist.  I would be hoping for a 404 instead.

For what it's worth, this appears to be a long running WP issue per this ticket

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20746

There are suggestions of fixes there, but I'd like to understand any change I deploy there since it won't be "official WP".  I'm thinking that understanding how that rule could lead to anything other than a self-rewrite would help me be confident in deployment of one of the suggested changes.

---

**EDIT:** Here's an example of the rule being applied:

```
[rid#7f58a5a5dcb0/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/wordpress/] applying pattern '^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)' to uri 'wp-content/invalid_directory/nothing.png'
[rid#7f58a5a5dcb0/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/wordpress/] rewrite 'wp-content/invalid_directory/nothing.png' -> 'wp-content/invalid_directory/nothing.png'
[rid#7f58a5a5dcb0/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/wordpress/] add per-dir prefix: wp-content/invalid_directory/nothing.png -> /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/invalid_directory/nothing.png
[rid#7f58a5a5dcb0/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/wordpress/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/wordpress/ with /
[rid#7f58a5a5dcb0/initial/redir#2] strip matching prefix: /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/invalid_directory/nothing.png -> wp-content/invalid_directory/nothing.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
> ```

I think the main intention of that directive is to prevent further processing of the file (ie. to prevent the request being forwarded to the front controller: `index.php`) when requesting a URL that starts `/wp-content`, `/wp-admin` or `/wp-includes`.

By rewriting to itself, the URL passes through unchanged and processing stops.

However, the resulting *substitution* is also *relative*, so whatever is stated as the `RewriteBase` will also be prefixed to the rewritten URL. In this case the `RewriteBase` is simply `/`, so it is indeed rewritten to itself on the first pass (assuming this `.htaccess` file is in the document root). I assume this must be intentional, otherwise they would have used a hyphen (`-`) as the *substitution*, as in the directive above.

This "shouldn't" result in a rewrite loop, since processing should stop if the URL passes through unchanged (the rewrite is essentially "ignored").

However, to be sure it's not changed, you could simply replace `$1` with `-` in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*.

If you enable full rewrite debugging, eg. `LogLevel rewrite:trace6` in the server config on Apache 2.4+ you should see exactly what is happening as it should show each iteration of the rewrite.

Comment: Thanks for the clues! I had read somewhere that this might be related to cases where the wordpress files are hosted outside of the root (either in a subfolder or above the webroot) but where users don't want the URL to reflect that.

Comment: Also, I added some logging info above.  It doesn't appear that Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) is smart enough to avoid re-running the engine. When I replaced the $1 with - it fixed the issue, so marking this as answered